# merge and save loaded stylesheets in browser to one file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to convert a website page with all of it's external stylesheets to a single html with inline css (not for email use but to include styled portions of that page into another website's page), I've found so far [CssToInlineStyles](http://classes.verkoyen.eu/css_to_inline_styles%20CssToInlineStyles.) wich does most of the job very well, but I still have to merge all stylesheets into one file and then pass it to that class.

Answer (score 0):

scrapbook for firefox seems fine, only drawback : no contol over changing urls of resources (images in html or in css) it make a whole snapshot of the webpage available offline with no overrides